# How to find the nearby users with my application?

Tags: android, algorithm, google-nearby

I'm currently developing an android application and now the requirement is to identify the users that are near to me who's using this application. Can anyone help me with this ?

Anyone got any sample code or algorithm ???

Answer (score 0):

You need to collect users Longitude and Latitude then compare users longitude and latitude over server and send result back to users.But the question you asked is vast topic it can't be explain like that but for the better result use [Spatial Databse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spatial_database)